# Stroke all paths in a GIMP File

Tags: gimp, tracing

I have been working on an image file which contains a lot of paths. The file is a flow field visualization picture, and I've traced the individual streamlines in the image with the path tool to generate a cleaner, easier to read and view, document. The file now contains several hundreds of paths that all need to be stroked.

Is there a way to stroke all of the paths at once that also allows me to retain the individual paths?

I know that there is the option to merge all paths, but I'd like to keep them separate. There are more images with very similar flow fields, and I hope that I can save some work time by reusing the paths and just manipulating the nodes.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you show an image of what you are trying to achieve, even if its just an example you found on the web. From your description it sounds like GIMP is probably not the right kind of software. TBH. It might be better to use vector software instead, such as Inkscape (also free and open source). It's much easier to work with paths in Inkscape

Answer (score 0):

See the [`ofn-stroke-fill-paths` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/).

See bottom of linked page for installation instructions.

ZIP also contains an HTML doc.